# IE HTTPS Problem

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, sockets

Has anyone seen this problem with IE ?

IE opens up a new socket for each of the new resources it loads in HTTPS , the problem is when the client is used for some time on IE with HTTPS these socets keeps accumulating and cause the webserver to choke till they are closed after some time

The following is the output of my  webserver which increases overtime when the browser is being used for some time. And when browser is closed the sockets reduce .

```
root@localhost:~# netstat -taup | grep http
tcp        0      0 *:www                   *:*                     LISTEN     14427/webs_http.bin
tcp        0      0 *:https                 *:*                     LISTEN     14426/webs_https.bi
tcp        0      0 10.201.11.16:https      172.23.34.41:4181       TIME_WAIT  -
tcp        0      0 10.201.11.16:https      172.23.34.41:4183       TIME_WAIT  -
tcp        0      0 10.201.11.16:https      172.23.34.41:4182       TIME_WAIT  -
tcp        0      0 10.201.11.16:https      172.23.34.41:4179       TIME_WAIT  -
tcp        0      0 10.201.11.16:https      172.23.34.41:4180       TIME_WAIT  -
tcp        0      0 10.201.11.16:https      172.23.34.41:4187       TIME_WAIT  -
tcp        0      0 10.201.11.16:https      172.23.34.41:4184       TIME_WAIT  -
tcp        0      0 10.201.11.16:https      172.23.34.41:4186       TIME_WAIT  -
tcp        0      0 10.201.11.16:https      172.23.34.41:4188       TIME_WAIT  -
tcp        0      0 10.201.11.16:https      172.23.34.41:4185       TIME_WAIT  -
```

Other browsers like firefox/Chrome does not have this problem .

Comment: What is on the actual page being accessed? Could it be some sort of ajax thing that IE keeps open while other browsers don't? What happens if you disable javascript and try again?

Comment: yes , This is a Ajax application i can see the IE opening and closing socket for the every request sent to webserver only in HTTPS mode. The same is true with the images / CSS getting downloaded from webserver .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be the HTTPS keep-alive which many default Apache configurations attempt to defeat?  I'm uncertain of this, but every Apache default configuration I've encountered in the last several years has included the following directive.

Try adding this to the SSL/443 VirtualHost configuration (assuming this is an Apache server -- not tagged specifically)

```
 SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
```

Comment: Its an webserver running in an embedded platform built with GoAhead webserver . But i understood what you mean , there may be some configuration on my webserver to do the setup as apache configuration you mentioned . Thanks for your help ! !